# error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0

Tags: linux, git, curl, openssl, archlinux

I use **Arch Linux** and this problem appears when trying to push on my rip

`error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0`

this issue when writing

> > git push origin master

`Counting objects: 65, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Writing objects: 100% (65/65), 76.27 KiB | 1.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 65 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date`

i'm change my **buffer size** and upgrade **git**, **curl**, **openssl** but doesn't work .

so any help pleas.

Comment: Where are you trying to push? GitHub? GitLab? Bitbucket? Somewhere else?

Comment: GitHub ..........

Comment: Not sure how long are you using Git & Github, but I am using it for a very long time and from yesterday I am having exactly the same error.

Comment: I use it for a very long time too, and I never see this error before......
Git was work fine.... but this error happened suddenly, and it happened with other people with different os's

Comment: Ok in windows it was the outdated Git Credential Manager problem. Updated from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/) and the error is gone. Probably there is one for Linux as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So I ran into the same issue and contacted github.com/contact. In the end, they gave the hint that solved it for me. I needed to change the git config to use TLSv1.2 instead of SSLv3:

```
git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

As GitHub support told me, in the beginning, the issue could be related to a change which they deployed a few months ago, that disables support for deprecated legacy TLS and SSH algorithms, including those that were used in older versions of some Git clients. You can find more information and advice here:

https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: Although it didn't help me with exactly the same error, there is a tip if you get `warning: unsupported ssl version TLSv1.2: using default` - type `tlsv1.2` in lowercase.

Comment: git config --global http.sslVersion tlsv1.2 to set it globally.

Comment: This worked after upgrading Git to version `2.37.3`. It didn't work before I did.

Comment: If you're not currently in a repo, you'll likely need to add the `--global` flag after `git config` or you'll get an error

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to mobile hotspot and push.

Comment: This worked for me. Probably there is an issue with my home wifi.

Comment: This solution worked for me, too. Thank you, what a tricky thing

Answer (score 1):

As R.singh said I changed my internet connection to Mobile hotspot and it worked for me like a magic !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34133461)

Answer (score 1):

This is the final answer:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by updating Git.
If you're on Windows run Command Prompt as Administrator and execute

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, these commands work

**1. git config http.postBuffer 524288000**

**2. git push**

if git push is not working then use this one

**1. git push origin branch-name**

Answer (score 0):

change your DNS to 0.0.0.0 and push!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).