# Why am I getting this github error message

Tags: git

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 55, done.
Counting objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: error:1404C3FC:SSL routines:ST_OK:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 14.31 MiB | 1.45 MiB/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: It [could be your SSL installation](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-git-clone-failed-with-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-error-1408f119-ssl-routines-ssl3-get-record-decryption-failed-or-bad-record-mac-errno-0/40464/6) or you're [using weak encryption that Github no longer supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720604/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-error140943fcssl-routinesssl3-re).

Comment: try this, git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720604/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-error140943fcssl-routinesssl3-re

Answer (score -1):

You need to change needed to the git config to use TLSv1.2 instead of SSLv3:

```
git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

You can find more information and advice here:

https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: Thnak you, I will try that

Comment: Updating git version solved the problem- thanks for the tip